# add loop within printf

Tags: bash, loops, text, printf

I'm working with some big script which produce some new input.sh file which consist of sequence of the commands step-by-step used as the input for some program called here pmemd.

Here I'd like to focus on how I obtain this input.sh. Using printf I have the following :

```
 printf "#setenv CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES "1"\nmpirun -np 8 pmemd.MPI -O -i ../in/minim.in -o minim.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./protein.inpcrd -r minim.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil.in -o equil.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./minim.restrt -r equil.restrt -x equil.nc -ref ./minim.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil2.in -o equil2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil.restrt -r equil2.restrt -x equil2.nc -ref equil.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil3.in -o equil3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil2.restrt -r equil3.restrt -x equil3.nc -ref equil2.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil4.in -o equil4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil3.restrt -r equil4.restrt -x equil4.nc -ref equil3.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_1.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil4.restrt -r equil5_1.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil4.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_1.restrt -r equil5_2.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_1.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_2.restrt -r equil5_3.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_2.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_3.restrt -r equil5_4.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_3.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_5.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_4.restrt -r equil5_5.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_4.restrt\npmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/md.in -o md_${P}_${com_n}.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_5.restrt -r md.restrt -x md.nc" > ./input.sh
```

which result in the input.sh eventually consisted of the

```
#setenv CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES 1
mpirun -np 8 pmemd.MPI -O -i ../in/minim.in -o minim.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./protein.inpcrd -r minim.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil.in -o equil.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./minim.restrt -r equil.restrt -x equil.nc -ref ./minim.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil2.in -o equil2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil.restrt -r equil2.restrt -x equil2.nc -ref equil.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil3.in -o equil3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil2.restrt -r equil3.restrt -x equil3.nc -ref equil2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil4.in -o equil4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil3.restrt -r equil4.restrt -x equil4.nc -ref equil3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_1.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil4.restrt -r equil5_1.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil4.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_1.restrt -r equil5_2.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_1.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_2.restrt -r equil5_3.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_3.restrt -r equil5_4.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_5.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_4.restrt -r equil5_5.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_4.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/md.in -o md_OR5P3_plus-carvone.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_5.restrt -r md.restrt -x md.nc
```

as you can see this method is not very comfortable because it's not easy to edit containt of the input.sh within the initial script when I need to add some modification of future input.sh. Also As you notice the file consist of fragment which i need to obtain as the result of the some looping because it consist of several steps like 5_1, 5_2 etc (here each next step use the previous one as the input)

```
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_1.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil4.restrt -r equil5_1.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil4.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_1.restrt -r equil5_2.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_1.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_2.restrt -r equil5_3.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_3.restrt -r equil5_4.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_5.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_4.restrt -r equil5_5.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_4.restrt
```

So I'd thankful if someone provide me with the ideas of how to add For or While loop within such printf operator or its alternatives.

Thanks for help!!

Gleb

Comment: Have you tried using a `for` loop (or two) yourself? If so, what problems did you encounter? Do you understand how to use the value of variables inside a string?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shell script that generates most of the lines in your post:

```
prev=minim
for i in '' $(seq 2 4); do
  cur=equil$i
  printf 'pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/%s.in -o %s.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c %s.restrt -r %s.restrt -x %s.nc -ref %s.restrt\n' $cur $cur $prev $cur $cur $prev
  prev=$cur
done
for i in $(seq 5); do
  cur=equil5_$i
  printf 'pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o %s.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c %s.restrt -r %s.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref %s.restrt\n' $cur $prev $cur $prev
  prev=$cur
done
```

This generates:

```
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil.in -o equil.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c minim.restrt -r equil.restrt -x equil.nc -ref minim.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil2.in -o equil2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil.restrt -r equil2.restrt -x equil2.nc -ref equil.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil3.in -o equil3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil2.restrt -r equil3.restrt -x equil3.nc -ref equil2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil4.in -o equil4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil3.restrt -r equil4.restrt -x equil4.nc -ref equil3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_1.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil4.restrt -r equil5_1.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil4.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil5_1.restrt -r equil5_2.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_1.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil5_2.restrt -r equil5_3.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil5_3.restrt -r equil5_4.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_5.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c equil5_4.restrt -r equil5_5.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_4.restrt
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but it seems to be that you're not comfortable with such a big giant `printf` line. So, why not just divide it up. You can use `>>` to *append* to a file. This way, each line in your `input.sh` is a separate `printf` line:

```
printf "#setenv CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \"1\"\n" > input.sh
printf "mpirun -np 8 pmemd.MPI -O -i ../in/minim.in -o minim.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./protein.inpcrd -r minim.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil.in -o equil.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./minim.restrt -r equil.restrt -x equil.nc -ref ./minim.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil2.in -o equil2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil.restrt -r equil2.restrt -x equil2.nc -ref equil.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil3.in -o equil3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil2.restrt -r equil3.restrt -x equil3.nc -ref equil2.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil4.in -o equil4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil3.restrt -r equil4.restrt -x equil4.nc -ref equil3.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_1.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil4.restrt -r equil5_1.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil4.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_1.restrt -r equil5_2.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_1.restrt\n >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_2.restrt -r equil5_3.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_2.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_3.restrt -r equil5_4.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_3.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_5.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_4.restrt -r equil5_5.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_4.restrt\n" >> input.sh
printf "pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/md.in -o md_${P}_${com_n}.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_5.restrt -r md.restrt -x md.nc\n" >> ./input.sh
```

Since `printf` doesn't automatically include a NL on the end, you could even divide up the individual `input.sh` lines for better readability:

```
printf " pmemd.cuda -O"         >> input.sh
printf " -i ../in/equil.in"     >> input.sh
printf " -o equil.out"          >> input.sh
printf " -p ./protein.parm7"    >> input.sh
printf " -c ./minim.restrt"     >> input.sh 
printf " -r equil.restrt"       >> input.sh
printf " -x equil.nc"           >> input.sh
printf " -ref ./minim.restrt"   >> input.sh
printf "\n"                     >> input.sh
```

Now, if something is changed, you can quickly find the parameter and modify it.

You could also combine that with [Chris Jester-Young](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457125/368630)'s suggestion of using a `for` loop to increment your values:

```
for cur in '' $(seq 2 4)
do
    printf ' pmemd.cuda -O '                >> input.sh
    printf ' -i ../in/equil%s.in '    $cur  >> input.sh
    printf ' -o equil%s.out'          $cur  >> input.sh
    printf ' -p ./protein.parm7"            >> input.sh
    printf ' -c equil%s.restrt'       $prev >> input.sh
    prinff ' -r equil%s.restrt'       $cur  >> input.sh
    printf ' -x equil%s.nc'           $cur  >> input.sh
    printf ' -ref equil%s.restrt\n'   $prev >> input.sh
    prev=$cur
done
```

Note how the spacing on each line makes it easier to read and understand the command.

Finally, if you don't mind writing out the entire file, you can use a *here* document.

The `<<` starts the *here* document. The `EOF` is the parameter that tells the *here* document when it ends. This could be anything. For example, it could be `INPUT_SH`. If I put that parameter in single quotes, the shell won't interpolate variables.

```
cat <<'EOF' > input.sh
#setenv CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES "1"
mpirun -np 8 pmemd.MPI -O -i ../in/minim.in -o minim.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./protein.inpcrd -r minim.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil.in -o equil.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  ./minim.restrt -r equil.restrt -x equil.nc -ref ./minim.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil2.in -o equil2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil.restrt -r equil2.restrt -x equil2.nc -ref equil.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil3.in -o equil3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil2.restrt -r equil3.restrt -x equil3.nc -ref equil2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil4.in -o equil4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil3.restrt -r equil4.restrt -x equil4.nc -ref equil3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_1.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil4.restrt -r equil5_1.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil4.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_2.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_1.restrt -r equil5_2.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_1.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_3.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_2.restrt -r equil5_3.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_2.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_4.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_3.restrt -r equil5_4.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_3.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/equil5.in -o equil5_5.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_4.restrt -r equil5_5.restrt -x equil5.nc -ref equil5_4.restrt
pmemd.cuda -O -i ../in/md.in -o md_${P}_${com_n}.out -p ./protein.parm7 -c  equil5_5.restrt -r md.restrt -x md.nc
EOF
```